# Peticion AsynTask()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post

Estoy haciendo una peticion a un webService desde un AsynTask() y me está dando el error de que la respuesta es nula.

He probado en el navegador a poner la URL de mi webservice y si me muestra el resultado de la consulta, por tanto el error está en la recepción de la consulta por parte del cliente android.

Os dejo el código:

```
public void peticionAsync()
    {
        PeticionAsync pA = new PeticionAsync();
        pA.execute(miUrl);
    }

    class PeticionAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
            return POST(miUrl);
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Persona p = new Persona();

            pd = new ProgressDialog(Listado.this);
            pd.setMessage("Conectando con el servidor");
            pd.show();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            json = gson.toJson(p);


        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            Log.i("RESULT: ","Consulta:"+result);
            if (result.trim().equals("0"))
            {
                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error en la conexión", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast1.show();

                Intent passIntent = new Intent();
                passIntent.setClass(Listado.this,Menu.class);
                startActivity(passIntent);
            }

            else{
                //Parsear result de JSON con GSON

                Log.i("JSONresumen",result);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                listaPlan = gson.fromJson(result, new TypeToken<List<PlanResumido>>(){}.getType());
                if (pd != null)
                {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
                actualizarDisplay();
            }



        }

        public String POST(String url) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            URL urlA;

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
                        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }

            try {
                urlA = new URL("https://safeplanapp.es/SPWS/SPlistadoPlanes.php");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            String data = json;
            String result = null;

            try
            {
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlA.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.connect();

                OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(data);
                writer.close();
                outputStream.close();

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                String line = null; StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Antes de realizar la peticióm, compruebo la conexión a internet:

```
 ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
        {
            peticionAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No hay conexión a INTERNET", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast2.show();
        }
```

Esto aparece en el LOG:

> W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
> certification path not found. W/System.err:     at
> org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:381)
> W/System.err:     at
> libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
> at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
> W/System.err:     at
> libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
> W/System.err:     at
> libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
> at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
> W/System.err:     at
> libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
> W/System.err:     at
> libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:165)
> W/System.err:     at
> midlab.Listado$PeticionAsync.POST(Listado.java:169)
> W/System.err:     at
> midlab.Listado$PeticionAsync.doInBackground(Listado.java:94)
> W/System.err:     at
> midlab.Listado$PeticionAsync.doInBackground(Listado.java:87)
> W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
> W/System.err:     at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) W/System.err:
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
> W/System.err:     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException:
> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
> certification path not found. W/System.err:     at
> org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:276)
> at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:197)
> W/System.err:     at
> org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:597)
> W/System.err:     at
> org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native
> Method)
> at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:378)
> ... 16 more W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
> certification path not found. W/System.err:   ... 21 more

Comment: Probaste la petición si funciona ? Que error es el que se muestra específicamente? Revisa el LogCat, que error se imprime?

Comment: @Jorgesys mira este es el JSON que devuelve el servidor _[{"id":"1","tipo":"B","usuario":"usu","organizador":"usu","actividad":"C","par":"","fInicio":"","date":"1970-01-01 01:00:00"}]_ En el **LOG** obtengo el valor null, y el error que me da es _E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at midlab.Listado$PeticionAsync.onPostExecute(Listado.java:116)
        at midlab.Listado$PeticionAsync.onPostExecute(Listado.java:87)_ que se corresponde con esta línea `if (result.trim().equals("0"))`

Comment: @Jorgesys edito la pregunta que repasando el log he visto cosas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tu peticiòn no devuelve ningun valor de hecho el valor que recibe onPostExecute es null:

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
        ...
        ...
```

Primeramente, si estas haciendo uso de un Asynctask el desactivar la politica para no permitir tareas en el hilo principal no es necesario, debes eliminar este bloque de còdigo:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =
                        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
```

El còdigo de la peticiòn es correcto de hecho veo que obtiene resultado:

```
[{"id":"1","tipo":"B","usuario":"safeplan@safeplan.es","organizador":"safeplan@safeplan.es","actividad":"Caza","paramo":"","fInicio":"","date":"1970-01-01 01:00:00"}]
```

Por lo tanto revisa estos dos puntos para solucionar el problema:

1. Asegura que el valor de miUrl es el valor de la url a la cual realizas la peticiòn.

private String miUrl = "https://safeplanapp.es/SPWS/SPlistadoPlanes.php";

2. Asegura tengas conexiòn a internet.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, eliminé el bloque de código que dijiste y comporbé tanto la URL como la conexión. Ademas me puse en contacto con el hosting para que revisaran los certificados SSL y la conexión, y está todo correcto. ¿Crees que si utilizo volley o retrofit se solucuionaría el error?

Comment: Tu código no debería fallar en la petición, que valor tiene miUrl aquí en este método: protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
            return POST(miUrl);
        }

Comment: tiene esta url https://safeplanapp.es/SPWS/SPlistadoPlanes.php. He probado desde android a hacer la petición al http sin la "s", es decir a http://safeplanapp.es/SPWS/SPlistadoPlanes.php y funciona, es un problema de android y los certificados ssl y tsl. Si lo buscas en el mismo stackoverflow hay bastantes preguntas pero yo no entiendo las respuestas. puedes mirar este ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39264056/android-java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexception-trust-anchor-for-certific